# Changing stylesheet based on session data

Tags: php

Ok I have a session started within my application and it gets a session variable that defines a theme.

I have this code, but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Basically I want this to select the correct stylesheet based on the theme the user chose at registration. So if they selected the Default theme I would need the default css file to be linked and so on...

I am fairly new to PHP so if it's completely wrong, tell me but please help and tell me what's wrong. We all start somewhere.

```
<?php 
$themeName = '$_SESSION["SESS_THEME_NAME"]';
if ($themeName == "Default") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme.css" />';
}
if ($themeName == "Army") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme-army.css" />';
}
if ($themeName == "Rocky Mountains") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme-rocky.css" />';
}
if ($themeName == "Chinese Temple") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme-chinese.css" />';
}
if ($themeName == "Boutique") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme-boutique.css" />';
}
if ($themeName == "Toxic") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme-toxic.css" />';
}
if ($themeName == "Aquamarine") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mws-theme-aquamarine.css" />';
}

?>
```

Comment: Whoever has -1 on this question, can you please provide feedback as to what I could do better next time or add to this question to make it a better question. Thank you. Constructive Criticism is better than simply down voting the question.

Comment: People often down vote when a basic question is asked. I guess they forget that they were a rookie once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the single quotes.. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php

`$themeName = $_SESSION["SESS_THEME_NAME"];`

If that doesn't work, make sure that you have started the session http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

`session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

make sure you start session on this page and edit the following,

```
$themeName = $_SESSION["SESS_THEME_NAME"];
```